# Why is reputation capped at 200 per day?

Tags: discussion, reputation

From the [Help Center](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation):

> You can earn a maximum of 200 reputation per day from any combination of the activities below. Bounty awards, accepted answers, and association bonuses are not subject to the daily reputation limit.

Why is there a limit on the amount of reputation that can be gained per day?

Comment: To keep lippy noobs in check.

Answer (score 11):

That limit mainly exists for two reasons :

1. It stops the site from being gamed by automated bots since the reputation limit gives a lot more time to the moderators to find them before they attain trusted reputation levels.
2. It slows down reputation gain from very active or lucky users so they do not gain abilities before they have time to understand how the site works properly.

More information can be found on the [meta.stackexhange.com](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22447/what-is-the-reasoning-behind-the-reputation-cap) answer to that question.

Comment: It's not about it being gamed by automated bots, just about it being gamed in general.

Answer (score 11):

Basically, it's a throttle on your trust level.

Major moderation functions are tied directly to reputation (things like editing, voting to close and deleting). The reputation cap serves to prevent you from gaining privileges that are beneficial to the site, but can be used for nefarious purposes too quickly.

Even if you somehow managed to hit the rep-cap *every single day* (no easy thing to do here), it would still take you somewhere around 10 days to get free editing privileges (2k), 15 to get close votes (3k) and 100 to get unfettered delete votes (20k).

This serves to force you to learn what a community is about before you get the tools to moderate it. This is a good and important thing.

Comment: So, in that case, why not have "No reputation cap" as a high-rep privilege? By the time you're there, you've proven yourself as a member of the community, and you'll have more chances to have extra rep for bounties and tag badges and the like?

Comment: @Jadasc because then Jon Skeet would be converging to infinity and the universe would be on the verge of ending?